# Maximum number of "almost orthogonal" vectors in a complex vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, inner-products

In a $d$ dimensional vector space defined over $\mathbb{C}$, how do I calculate the largest number $N(\epsilon, d)$ of vectors $\{V_i\}$ which satisfies the following properties. Here $\epsilon$ is small but finite compared to 1.

$$\langle V_i, V_i\rangle = 1$$

$$|\langle V_i, V_j\rangle| \leq \epsilon, i \neq j$$

Some examples are as follows.

1. $N(0, d)$ = d
2. $N\left(\frac{1}{2}, 2\right)$ = 3
3. $N\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 2\right) = 6$

How do I obtain any general formula for $N(\epsilon, d)$. Even an approximate form for $N(\epsilon, d)$ in the large $d$ and small $\epsilon$ limit works fine for me.

EDIT: The problem is now resolved. See the cross-posted answer to the same question [at Math Overflow.](https://mathoverflow.net/a/336395/78150)

Comment: I think this is a hard problem in general. One could probably find an explicit bound of the form $N(\varepsilon, d)=d$ if $\varepsilon < f(d)$ for some specific function $f$ but computing the exact number of vectors for bigger $\varepsilon$ seems difficult.

Comment: @quarague That is why I was hoping if one could find an approximate form for (,) in the large  and small  limit.

Comment: crossposted: https://mathoverflow.net/q/336387/11260

Comment: You can model the space of vectors as a projective space around the origin. (a hyper sphere of radius $1$ where opposite points are identified). Then $e$ determines a "radius" around each vector-point, in which other vector-points are not allowed to be. You can half this radius and you obtain something like a (n-1) sphere-packing problem on an (n)-sphere/projective plane. 
https://omlc.org/classroom/ece532/class1/gifs/spherecircle.gif 
This can give upper and lower bounds depending on $e$, tough I'm not sure of the exact number.

Comment: @user3257842 I was precisely trying that. Not much luck. :(

Comment: how small do you need $e$ to be? if it's small enough, it will not change $d$ . As it goes to $1$, the number of vectors goes to infinity at a $(\frac{1}{1-e})^{n-1}$ rate, I think.

Comment: @user3257842 True. For my case, $\epsilon$ needs to be of the order of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{d}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the $n+1$ elementary basis vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. The endpoints form the regular simplex, ie the tetrahedron equivalent in $n$ dimensions and all lie in a $n$-dim hyperplane. The center of this simplex is the point $(\frac{1}{n+1}, .., \frac{1}{n+1})$. Hence the vectors from the center to the corners of this $n$-dim tetrahedron have pairwise equal angles to each other. I believe this construction gives the arrangement of $d+1$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$ with angles closed to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Hence this construction should provide the threshhold for $\varepsilon$ where $N(\varepsilon, d)=d+1$.

To compute $\varepsilon$, pick two of the vectors, say $v_1=(1-\frac{1}{n+1}, -\frac{1}{n+1}, .., -\frac{1}{n+1})$ and $v_2=(-\frac{1}{n+1}, .., -\frac{1}{n+1},  1-\frac{1}{n+1})$. I get $\varepsilon=\frac{3d-1}{d(d+1)}$ so for $\varepsilon < \frac{3d-1}{d(d+1)}$ we have $N(\varepsilon, d)=d$ and $N(\frac{3d-1}{d(d+1)}, d)=d+1$.